# describe-task-definition not returning hostname value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I have the need to find the hostname of my ECS task via the CLI, which according to the Amazon documentation should be available via the CLI:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-task-definition.html

However, when I run the describe-task-definition it is not returning the information:

```
> aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition my-test-task:1
{
    "taskDefinition": {
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "networkMode": "bridge",
        "family": "my-test-task",
        "placementConstraints": [],
        "requiresAttributes": [
            {
                "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
            },
            {
                "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
            }
        ],
        "volumes": [
            {
                "host": {
                    "sourcePath": "/opt/cf/rails-app/public/"
                },
                "name": "ruby-on-rails-public-volume"
            }
        ],
        "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:accountId:task-definition/my-test-task:1",
        "containerDefinitions": [
            {
                "memoryReservation": 1024,
                "environment": [
                    {
                        "name": "DATABASE_HOSTNAME",
                        "value": "hostname"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "PUMA_WORKERS",
                        "value": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "RAILS_ENV",
                        "value": "staging"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "DATABASE_NAME",
                        "value": "ruby-on-rails"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "DEBIAN_FRONTEND",
                        "value": "noninteractive"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "PORT",
                        "value": "8080"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "LANG",
                        "value": "en_US.UTF-8"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "DATABASE_PASSWORD",
                        "value": "cf"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "DATABASE_USER",
                        "value": "cf"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "PUMA_MAX_THREADS",
                        "value": "6"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "my-test-task",
                "mountPoints": [
                    {
                        "sourceVolume": "ruby-on-rails-public-volume",
                        "containerPath": "/opt/cf/rails-app/public/"
                    }
                ],
                "image": "accountId.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/cf/rails:latest",
                "cpu": 1024,
                "portMappings": [
                    {
                        "protocol": "tcp",
                        "containerPort": 8080,
                        "hostPort": 8080
                    }
                ],
                "command": [
                    "puma",
                    "-C",
                    "config/puma.rb"
                ],
                "essential": true,
                "volumesFrom": []
            }
        ],
        "revision": 1
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I need to do to get that value included.  I confirmed I am running the latest CLI.

Thanks!

Comment: a task definition is just instructions on how to create a task.  You will need to describe the actual task that is created from the task definition and container instance that it is running on to know the IP/hostname of where the task is running.

Comment: Thanks, but describe-tasks doesn't include the hostname information.  What is the hostname referring to that is included in the describe-task-definition information?  Is there anyway else to determine this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the hoostname is not defined to task definition. Its defined to container definition inside task definition. Secondly, There is no default hostname, You have to explicitly define the hostname in the container definition while creating task definition revision. By default, it uses container id as the hostname.